# Docker run doesn't show dotnet run output

Tags: c#, docker, opc-ua

I'm trying to dockerize a C# OPC UA Client but, unfortunately, I've this error:

```
Unhandled exception. Opc.Ua.ServiceResultException: Error establishing a connection: BadNotConnected
at Opc.Ua.Bindings.ChannelAsyncOperation`1.End(Int32 timeout, Boolean throwOnError)
at Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaSCUaBinaryClientChannel.EndSendRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaSCUaBinaryTransportChannel.EndSendRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at Opc.Ua.Bindings.UaSCUaBinaryTransportChannel.SendRequest(IServiceRequest request)
at Opc.Ua.DiscoveryClient.GetEndpoints(RequestHeader requestHeader, String endpointUrl, StringCollection localeIds, StringCollection profileUris, EndpointDescriptionCollection& endpoints)
at Opc.Ua.DiscoveryClient.GetEndpoints(StringCollection profileUris)
at Opc.Ua.Client.CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint(String discoveryUrl, Boolean useSecurity, Int32 discoverTimeout)
at client.Program.OPCUAClass.InitializeOPCUAClient() in C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\client\Program.cs:line 182
at client.Program.OPCUAClass..ctor(String serverAddres, String serverport, Dictionary`2 taglist, Boolean sessionrenewalRequired, Double sessionRenewalMinutes, String nameSpace) in C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\client\Program.cs:line 98
at client.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\client\Program.cs:line 58
```

Has anyone already had this error? Or has anyone already dockerized a C # client know how a dockerfile should be written in this case?

The client doesn't have an interface but it only print nodes on terminal at data change.
I usually use the dotnet run command to run the client.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal

COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish/ App/
COPY tagsList.txt App/
WORKDIR /App

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "client.dll"]
```

And here are Program.cs lines with errors:

58:
`myOPCUAServer = new OPCUAClass(endpointURL, "62541", TagList, true, 1, "4");`

98:
`InitializeOPCUAClient();`

182:
`application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 2048).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

I already tried to change the opc address from localhost to 0.0.0.0 but nothing has changed.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 will never work. When you see that mentioned on the net, it's always specified as what IP addresses to accept connections *from* and 0.0.0.0 means everybody. You're the client and you need to specify the address of your OPC UA server. Localhost doesn't work, since localhost is the container where your app is running. Where is your OPC UA server running?

Comment: The server (an Ignition Simulator Device) is running on my pc and for this reason i used localhost(127.0.0.1)

Comment: OK. If your host is Windows or Mac, then try `host.docker.internal`. If your host is Linux, then use `172.17.0.1`. That should be the address of the host machine.

Comment: Where I should use host.docker.internal? In my server address? ("opc.tcp://host.docker.internal:62541")

Comment: Yes. It's the network address of the host machine from inside the container.

Comment: I changed it and next i run docker run command and the problem remains